# not all headers available in $_SERVER [PHP]

Tags: php, apache

I have some custom header, and it's not visible in `$_SERVER`, but it visible with help `apache_request_headers()`.

And such problem existing only in one Windows based Apache version (OpenServer). On Mac and Linux Apache pass all headers to php, and I can see it in `$_SERVER` variable... maybe there is some restriction for windows ? or is there any settings in apache.conf which can activate passing all header to mod_php ?

Comment: Is php running as cgi or apache module?

Answer (score 4):

When PHP is running as a Apache module on Windows, you won't see all headers on $_SERVER autoglobal array.

You have to retrieve them with apache_request_headers(). You could use some code to obtain cross platform deployment:

```
function GetHeader($myheader) {
  if (isset($_SERVER[$myheader])) {
    return $_SERVER[$myheader];
  } else {
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    if (isset($headers[$myheader])) {
      return $headers[$myheader];
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

If you PHP is newer enough, you could also try getallheaders().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Comment: actually i re installed openserver and problem is gone :)

Answer (score 0):

From PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

On the comments, notice that:

**On Windows IIS 7 you must use $_SERVER['LOCAL_ADDR'] rather than $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] to get the server's IP address.**

It seems that some variable names are different in windows, so you'll have to find them out. If you have a close look at the documentation comments there are a few workarounds for some of them

Comment: though that doesn't help if headers are not there at all, which might also be the case

Answer (score 0):

php  `$_SERVER` is weired better option is to use `apache_request_headers()`

But if you want to still use  `$_SERVER` add `HTTP_` and replace all `-` to `_` and the **last thing to remember if the request header has `_` than it will not be parsed at all (lost)**